# Cyclotomic polynomial formula: is it valid in an arbitrary field?

Tags: cyclotomic-polynomials

Let $F$ be a field and $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then an element $\varepsilon \in \overline{F}$, being $\overline{F}$ an algebraic closure of $F$, is called a $n$-th root of unity if it is a root of the polynomial $X^n - 1 \in F[X]$. If I denote by $W_n$ the set of the $n$-th roots of unity, then it is a cyclic group and after I define the $n$-th cyclotomic polynomial by
$$
{\phi}_n(X) = \prod_{\varepsilon \in W_n^*} (X - \varepsilon)\mbox{,}
$$
where $W_n^*$ is the set of the elements $\varepsilon \in W_n$ such that $\langle \varepsilon \rangle = W_n$ (it is the set of the $n$-th primitive roots of unity). And now I can make my question: is the formula
$$
X^n - 1 = \prod_{d \mid n} {\Phi}_d(X)
$$
valid for each field $F$ or I need to consider $F = \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Your set $W_n^*$ is NOT what is usually defined as "the set of $n$th primitive roots of unity", if the characteristic of $F$ divides $n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are subtleties if $n\cdot1_F=0_F$. If $F$ has characteristic $p$, then we have 
$$X^p-1=(X-1)^p.$$
This implies $W_{p}^*=W_{p^2}^*=\{1_F\}$, and the formula fails.

---

Other than this, it does hold. See [a relatively recent answer by yours truly](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2727392/11619).

Comment: Why does the formula fail? Is it not possible to obtain ${\Phi}_p(X) = {(X - 1)}^{p - 1}$?

Comment: This is uncomfortably close to being a dupe, actually. Switching to CW for I should not try and get paid twice for the same work.

Comment: @joseabp91 Because $W_p^*$ has a single element $1$ it follows from your definition that $\Phi_p(X)=X-1$. Similarly $\Phi_{p^2}(X)=X-1$. Therefore the formula fails when $n=p$ and when $n=p^2$. It actually fails for a similar reason whenever $p\mid n$.

Comment: What happens if $W_p^* = \{1\}$?

Comment: $W_p=\{1\}$, so $W_p^*=\{1\}$. Therefore $\Phi_p(X)$ has degree $1$.

Comment: Oh I see, the contradiction follows from the equality $X - 1 = {(X - 1)}^{p - 1}$, right? They should have the same degree and we have not it for $p > 2$.

Comment: Correct @joseabp91. $p=2$ is, indeed, a special case. I knew there was a reason why I brought up $p^2$!!! In characteristic two your definition also leads to $\Phi_4(X)=X-1$ :-)

Comment: Can I state now that the next statement in an arbitrary field is false? This: if $\varepsilon$ is a $n$-th root of unity and $m$-th root of unity, where $n , m \in \mathbb{N}$ satisfy $\gcd(n , m) = 1$, then $\varepsilon = 1$.