# Prove $Q_{mp} = Q_{m}(x^p)$ when prime $p$ divides $m$. ($Q$ is cyclotomic polynomial over some finite field $K$)

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields, extension-field, cyclotomic-polynomials

All I know is playing with this fact that $Q_{mp}(x) = \dfrac{x^{mp}-1}{\prod_{d|mp}Q_d(x)}$ and I really did many calculations but they went nowhere. Also I proved that $Q_{mp}(x) = Q_m(x^p)/Q_m(x)$ if prime $p$ doesn't divide $m$. Combination of latter result and induction didn't help me through and it seems I need more.

Comment: What is your definition of a cyclotomic polynomial over a finite field?

Comment: $\prod_{(n,s)=1} (x-\zeta^s)$ where $\zeta \in F_{p^r}$ is a primitive root of $x^n-1$. ($F_{p^r}$ is splitting field of $x^n-1$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proof based only on the definition of the cyclotomic polynomial:

I will denote by $\Phi_n(X)$ the $n$-th cyclotomic polynomial. If $\varepsilon = e^{\frac{2i\pi}{n}} = \cos(\frac{2\pi}{n})+i\sin(\frac{2\pi}{n})$, then
$$\Phi_n(X) = \prod_{1\le i \le n \\ (i,n)=1} (X-\varepsilon^i)$$
Now consider $m, p$ such that $p$ is a prime number and $p \mid m$. Take $\xi = e^{\frac{2i\pi}{pm}} = \cos(\frac{2\pi}{mp})+i\sin(\frac{2\pi}{mp})$. Then:
$$\Phi_{mp}(X) = \prod_{1\le i \le mp \\ (i,mp)=1} (X - \xi^i) = \prod_{1\le i \le mp \\ (i,m)=1} (X - \xi^i) = \prod_{1\le i \le m \\ (i,m)=1} \prod_{j=0}^{p-1}(X - \xi^{jm+i} )$$
Since $\xi^p = e^{\frac{2i\pi}{m}} = \cos(\frac{2\pi}{m})+i\sin(\frac{2\pi}{m})$ we have:
$$\Phi_m(X) = \prod_{1\le i \le m \\ (i,m)=1} (X- \xi^{pi})$$ and $$\Phi_m(X^p) = \prod_{1\le i \le m \\ (i,m)=1} (X^p- \xi^{pi})$$
Fix some $1\le i \le m$ with $(i,m)=1$ and consider the polynomial $f(X) = X^p - \xi^{pi}$. It is very easy to observe that $f$ has $p$ distinct roots: $\xi^i, \xi^{m+i}, \ldots \xi^{(p-1)m+i}$. Since $f$ has degree $p$, these are all the roots of $f$. Therefore $$X^p - \xi^{pi} = f(X) = (X-\xi^i)(X-\xi^{m+i})\ldots(X - \xi^{(p-1)m+i}) = \prod_{j=0}^{p-1}(X - \xi^{jm+i} )$$ which finishes the proof.

Comment: I should have mentioned but I didn't specify base field. It's like you did it over field of complex numbers which I'm not sure could be carried to an arbitrary finite field. (Also title has been corrected)

Comment: How do you define the $7$-th cyclotomic polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_4$?

Comment: $\prod_{(7,s)=1} (x-\zeta^s)$ where $\zeta$ is a primitive root of $x^7-1$ in the extenion field of $F_4$. Also it can be proven that its coefficients should be in the prime subfield. Am I missing some point? It was supposed to be indefinable?

Comment: Ok. Do you find [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2727378/is-the-image-of-phi-nx-in-mathbbzx-in-mathbbf-qx-still-a-cyclo?noredirect=1&lq=1) post useful?

Comment: No, Should I? I feel dumb and frustrated now. We defined polynomial over some finite field, so I don't understand why image of zero-characteristic field would be beneficial for us. Cyclotomic polynomial of some degree inside finite field can be completely irrelevant to any zero-characteristic field. Can you explain more?

Comment: Consider the finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ with $q=r^t$ for some prime number $r$ and $t \ge 1$. Assume that $(r,m)=1$. I proved that $\Phi_{mp}(X) = \Phi_{m}(X^p)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Reducing modulo $r$ we get that the same equality is true over $\mathbb{F}_q$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128358/discussion-between-cos-dm-math21-and-hnrzi).

Answer (score 1):

**Big Hint:**

Step $1$: Show that $Q_{mp}(x)$ and $Q_{m}(x^p)$ have the same degree

**Proof:** By assumption $mp = np^i$ where $\text{gcf}(n,p) = 1$, $i\geq 2$, and $m= np^{i-1}$.

The roots of $Q_{mp}$ are the primitive $(mp)^{th}$ roots of unity and there are $\phi(mp) = \phi(np^i)$ which is also the degree of $Q_{mp}$. But we also have,

$$\phi(np^i) = \phi(n)\phi(p^i) = \phi(n)(p^{i} - p^{i-1}) = p\phi(n)(p^{i-1} - p^{i-2}) = p\phi(m)$$

The right hand side is the degree of $Q_m(x^p)$. So $Q_{mp}$ and $Q_{m}(x^p)$ have the same degree.

Step $2$: Show that any root of $Q_{mp}$ is also a root of $Q_{m}(x^p)$. In other words, show that if $\zeta$ is a primitive $(mp)^{th}$ root of unity, then $\zeta^p$ is a primitive $m^{th}$ root of unity.

(You can do it in reverse and show that any root of $Q_{m}(x^p)$ is a root of $Q_{mp}$, but there are only like $5$ people in the world who would find that more natural and they're weird).